# Multi-Term does not color the whole background

Tags: colors, multi-term

I want a black background in my multi-term buffer and therefore, I call :

```
(custom-set-variables
'(term-default-bg-color "#000000")
'(term-default-fg-color "#dddd00"))
```

in my emacs initialization file. But, it does not color the entire background. See the attached image. I want the entire background color as black.[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with `multi-term`. You're commenting about the behavior of `term` (`ansi-term`?), of which `multi-term` is a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the background is white where the text is.  `term-default-bg-color` and `term-default-fg-color` are obsolete, use the `term` face instead.

I'm not sure there's a way to make the background of the terminal anything other than `default` face, so you'll want the `term` face to inherit its background color from `default`.

```
(set-face-attribute 'term nil :background 'unspecified)
```

or `M-x customize-face RET term RET`.